# Produce charts making $M=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb R^2:a^2+b^2=1\}$ an oriented smooth manifold

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm stuck on this question:

> Let $M=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb R^2:a^2+b^2=1\}$ and define $\omega : \mathbb R^2\to\Lambda_1(\mathbb R^2)$ by $\omega(a,b)=(a+b)dx.$
>
> Produce charts making $M$ an oriented smooth manifold, and with this orientation compute $\int_M\omega$.

My initial idea:

$Ψ_1 : (−π, π) → M $and $Ψ_2 : (0, 2π) → M$

$Ψ_1(t) := (cos(t),sin(t)), t ∈ (−π, π)$

$Ψ_2(t) := (cos(t),sin(t)), t ∈ (0, 2π).$

Is this correct so far?

What would be the best approach to this? I'm worried about over complicating it.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you are doing well, but with a single chart you are done, pick one of them. Notice that you'd be leaving out  only one point, that doesn't contribute to the interal. You're close to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct idea. You can be a teensy bit more general by taking all functions $t \mapsto (\cos t, \sin t)$ whose domain is an interval $(a, b)$ with $b - a < 2 \pi$ (okay, perhaps this is over-complicating things a bit). In any event, the transition functions all look like $t \mapsto t + 2\pi n$ for a fixed $n \in \mathbf{Z}$ so the derivatives are all $1$ and hence the atlas is smooth and oriented.

In terms of actually computing $\int_M \omega$, you only need one chart with domain $(-\pi, \pi)$ or $(0, 2\pi)$ because the omission of a single point does not change the value of the integral.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's very helpful! I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but would it then be acceptable to go $\int_0^{2\pi}(a+b)(-sin(t))dt $ and substitute $a=cos(t)$ and $b=sin(t)$ or do I keep $a$ and $b$ as they are? I'm guessing the latter, but I thought I should check.

Comment: @CKrucz You take the form $\omega = (a + b)da$ and substitute $a = \cos t$ and $b = \sin t$ to get $(\cos t + \sin t)d\cos t = -\sin t(\cos t + \sin t)dt$. If you know [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) you can use that to double check. Note that $\partial(x + y)/\partial y = 1$ so you get the integral of $-1 dx \wedge dy$ over the unit disk, which gives you $- \pi$.